# background-image: in CSS dont load in DIV

Tags: html, css

I m desesperate, i look an example of css cards but is not working for me
the html code of frotadan.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Frota Daniel</title>
 <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet " />
 </head>
<body>
<section>
    <div class="card">
        <h2>Free Willy</h2>
        <div class="card-image boat1"></div>
         <p>Texto </p>
     </div>
     <div class="card">
        <h2>Yu</h2>
        <div class="card-image"></div>
         <p>Texto </p>
     </div>
     <div class="card">
        <h2>Xalana</h2>
        <div class="card-image"></div>
         <p>texto </p>
        </div>
        </section>
        </body>                
        </html>
```

And this are the code of mais.css

```
   *{ box-sizing:border-box; padding: 0; margin:0; }

body { background: rgb(27, 27, 27); }   

.container {    display:flex; justify-content: center;  }

.card { background: white; width: 200px; height: 400px; 
       margin: 10px;} 

.card-image { background-color: aqua; height: 150px; 
 margin-bottom: 15px;  }

 .boat1 { background-image: url('img/x4.jpeg');  }
```

x4.jpeg are in the img folder Why dont charge??

Comment: Have you tried prefacing the URL of `x4.jpeg` with a leading slash, so it would be`./img/x4.jpeg`?

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser to see what your server responds to the request of `x4.jpeg` and what the full URL of that request is.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the address of the photo. "../img/x4.jpeg"

```css
.boat1 { background-image: url('../img/x4.jpeg');  }
```

Comment: Thanks thanks I use  use the dots and work very well